# Does the U.S. Supreme Court have jurisdiction over the constitutionality of an impeachment?

Tags: constitutional-law, us-supreme-court, impeachment

A [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/62565/7226) arose on Politics SE asking why the constitutionality to continue an impeachment trial (whose prime purpose is, presumably, to remove an official from office) after the official has left office has not been decided.

There was a disagreement in the comments: While it is almost universally agreed that there is no judicial review of *how* the trial was conducted, including its result (because it's the Senate's supreme privilege), the case was not so clear with a review of *whether* the impeachment was constitutional to begin with.

Could the Supreme Court declare an entire impeachment process unconstitutional?

Comment: duplicate of [Are US Senate impeachment convictions reviewable by the Supreme Court](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48304/are-us-senate-impeachment-convictions-reviewable-by-the-supreme-court)  While this question attempts to differentiate itself from the linked one, it is still not sufficiently different from the linked question.  The currently-highest-upvoted answer to the linked question answers this one as well.

Comment: @grovkin Does it? I had read that question and answer and couldn't find an answer to my question. The answer discusses a specific rule *governing the **how** of the impeachment*, not the question *whether* to impeach that judge was constitutional. Correct me if I misread the answer but the constitutionality of conducting the impeachment at all was not disputed at all.

Comment: I read all the answers and comments on the linked question and could not find an answer to this question either. I wonder whether (assuming Trump had been convicted) the attorneys could appeal to the Supreme Court to rule on the question of whether the trial was constitutional. In particular, based on Article 1 Sec. 3 "When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside:". I know the Senate already voted twice that the majority thought the trial was constitutional.

Comment: The alleged dup is really not one: Seems to me that they are procedural questions.

Comment: If you *have* read it and have *not* understood it, then there is little I can do to help other than repeat some of what's already stated.  While the petition was to the court was more narrow, the court decided, at least for the time being, that it cannot review questions related to impeachment at all (Scouter's concurrency notwithstanding).  This preempted both the question brought up by Nixon's petition *as well as* many other questions.  The question that you asked is one of such questions.  The answer to the linked question has the quote which contains the relevant sentence.

Comment: You may also read through the answers to [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30736/what-is-the-meaning-of-high-crimes-and-misdemeanors/30884).  While the question is different, the background which is presented in some of the answers may provide more context.  Or you could do a search on the word "justiciable" on this site to see even more answers (most of which are about the process impeachment).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thanks for letting me know, the question is interesting.

Comment: I have to agree that I don't think this is a dupe. Nixon challenged the procedure as unconstitutional and the courts said they couldn't review the procedure because that is the sole power of the Senate. I don't see anything in the decision that says courts can't review anything related to the impeachment power; I imagine that if Congress impeached me, a private citizen, the SC would have something to say about it.

Answer (score 9):

Part of the problem you'll find is that there are so few impeachments in U.S. History (Only 21 articles of Impeachment have ever been drafted, of which only 8 resulted in convictions) and SCOTUS is so selective on cases it chooses to hear, that only one case has ever been heard and that was upheld (*Nixon v. United States*).   In that case, SCOTUS ruled that it did not have jurisdiction to rule on the legal question before it (was the new trial format a proper trial by the senate), but did not have an opinion one way or another to suggest that SCOTUS could not review other cases that come before it.  One of the reasons they also haven't is in order to have a legal case in the U.S., the plaintiff must suffer actual harm.  More impeachments ended without a conviction than with either acquittal (8), resignation before trial conclusion (4), and expulsion from senate (1, and will never occur again as Congressional office holders are not impeachable following this particular case).

Since no harm was caused and courts do not rule on hypotheticals, a case with actual harm (conviction) must occur in order for SCOTUS to even consider hearing the case.  *Nixon* does not bar SCOTUS from hearing more appeals resulting from Impeachment, it only bars those relating to the manner in which the senate chooses to hold the trial.

Comment: Trump could file for compensation of his legal expenses on the grounds that the impeachment was unconstitutional (which were probably substantial considering the speed with which he was burning his lawyers). Indirectly such a suit would have to consider the constitutionality of the impeachment.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica:  I'm not sure he can.  The right to a compentent attorney only applies during criminal trial, not civil (normally you can claim legal fees in addition to damages awarded if you win).  Impeachment is quasi-criminal but I don't know where compensation rests.

Comment: A small point: many impeachments comprised more than one article of impeachment, so if 21 people were impeached, the number of articles of impeachment that have passed the house will be larger than 21.  A related point: some articles of impeachment were drafted and put to a vote and failed to pass the house, while others never made it to the floor, so the number of articles of impeachment put to a vote will be even larger, and the number drafted but never put to the house for a vote will be larger still.

Comment: 21 Articles of Impeachment... of a US President? The count is actually 4... Andrew Johnson, Bill Clinton, Trump, Trump. Of which, none resulted in conviction. Where are you sourcing your Impeachment stats?

Comment: @SnakeDoc: The answer clearly says impeachments, not impeachments *of a US President.*

Comment: @Kevin No, but it does talk about the Senate, it's power over an impeachment, and the SCOTUS jurisdiction over impeachment proceedings, which are all to do with a US President.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The Senate also tries impeachments of judges.

Comment: @SnakeDoc There have been 21 impeachment proceedings in congress, of which, four were presidents.  Impeachment is used to remove any federal officer not in the legislature from office.   Of the 21, four were POTUS, 1 was a cabinet official, 1 was a Senator (setting the presidence that Legislature members are not impeachable), and 15 were Federal Judges.

Comment: @SnakeDoc:  Chief Justice of SCOTUS is only required to be judge in impeachment if the impeached officer is the president.

Comment: Ugh. Nixon vs. United States is a disaster of a precedent. Not that Nixon had a chance anyway; but the trial proceedings denied him the right to confront witnesses. Such a precedent must not become established.

Comment: @hszmv the chief justice does not act as a judge in a presidential impeachment trial but rather as the presiding officer of the senate.

Comment: @Joshua Nixon v. US was not a criminal prosecution; neither was the impeachment trial.

Comment: @phoog And the presiding officer of a court is called a judge.  The Senate is referred to as "The Court of Impeachment" when acting in its capacity during the Impeachment process.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @hszmv is correct and I fully agree with it. I would add a few additional points:

**Not All People Impeached Are Removed From Office**

A ban on holding future public office is imposed in only a minority of impeachments, and can only be litigated if the person seeks to hold such an office and has a non-speculative chance of obtaining one. In some ways this is the provision most ripe for litigation in the courts because it lasts the longest.

**SCOTUS doesn't have a monopoly on constitutional law**

Every single federal judge has the authority and the obligation to rule on constitutional issues that come before that judge. The U.S. Supreme Court does not have exclusive jurisdiction over constitutional issues, and would almost never have original jurisdiction in any case presented over the legality of impeachment proceedings.

**It takes a long time to reach SCOTUS and cases can become moot**

A case reaches the U.S. Supreme Court, if at all, by being litigated in a trial court and then an intermediate appellate court (possibly with *en banc* review in a federal appeal, or an intermediate state appellate court and then a state supreme court) first. This takes time, and many impeachment issues are time sensitive.

For example, any issue about the legality of an impeachment proceeding related to the potential removal from office sanction became moot, and beyond the jurisdiction of the courts, in the case of Donald Trump's second impeachment on January 20, 2021. At that point, only the legality of a bar on holding future public offices, if he had been convicted by the U.S. Senate, and if he had sought a future public office anyway, would have been justiciable. Since it takes a long time for litigation to work its way to the U.S. Supreme Court, impeachment issues will often become moot before it can consider them.

**Federal courts are barred from considering hypothetical cases**

The ban on the U.S. Supreme Court considering hypothetical cases is considered to be a binding rule of constitutional law that is jurisdictional under the "case or controversy clause" of the U.S. Constitution.

**Impeached individuals are uniquely unsympathetic but others lack standing**

Few people other than the impeached individual would have standing to litigate issues related to impeachment. So, you are left mostly with people whom two-thirds of the U.S. Senate voted to remove from office going to the courts asking to get their jobs back, and an even smaller subset of people whom two-thirds of the U.S. Senate voted  to remove from office and a majority votes to bar from holding future public offices, appealing to the courts for relief in litigated cases. People in those shoes are not sympathetic figures. You have to have messed up pretty badly  to each such bipartisan scorn. Unsurprisingly, courts are ill inclined to cut them a break in a close case, which makes such people unlikely to resort to the courts for relief.

Comment: Let's assume that a former president gets convicted (is that the word?) in the impeachment trial and additionally is barred from future public offices; do I understand you correctly that he would he have to sue at the district court to challenge the constitutionality even though he was impeached by the Senate?

Comment: @Peter: He certainly can't sue in the Supreme Court. That was settled way back in *Marbury v. Madison.* And you can't bring suit before the Senate itself, because the Senate is not a court in the first place. So where else is the ex-president going to go?

Comment: @Kevin The District Court for the District of Columbia if he wanted his job back and it hadn't expired. The court with jurisdiction of election administration in a place that denies him ballot access if he had been convicted and was fighting the disqualification from holding office.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica He would have to sue in the trial court of general jurisdiction where he was denied an ability to seek public office, could be a state trial court, could be a federal trial court, it would depend on the office in question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you mean by “unconstitutional”.  They almost certainly would not rule that the Constitution forbade Congress from having an impeachment trial, even if it was something insane like impeaching a new born baby.

Any decision on that front would unduly restrict Congress. If a court can say the **process** is unconstitutional, then **while it’s happening** lower courts would have jurisdiction over the impeachment.  That is something that is clearly forbidden by Constitution.

What they could rule, is that a **Judgement** was not constitutionally valid. So, in the case of of our little baby, they could rule that the Judgment was unconstitutional and that baby was eligible to run for whatever office it qualified for.  Same thing could happen if they impeached a President, and have someone other than the Chief Justice preside, or added something else onto the Judgement like a fine or jail.

The most likely scenarios for them to rule on is of course a successful impeachment for a former office holder or successful impeachment for actions that took place before holding office.  But it’s really unlikely that it will ever happen, because in order to have such a ruling, someone would have to lose, and then appeal.  Impeachments are so rare that both losing and having grounds for an appeal is really unlikely.  Controversial impeachments are unlikely to be successful, non-controversial impeachments are unlikely to have grounds for appeal.

Comment: "They almost certainly would not rule that the Constitution forbade Congress from having an impeachment trial, even if it was something insane like impeaching a new born baby." They might actually intervene in that particular extreme example (or a case of an impeachment trial of a state governor, in a slightly less extreme example) because impeachment applies only to federal officials as a threshold matter, and the trial itself would be a violation of rights in that case, unlike someone who is or ever was a federal official.